# CakePHP - How to go about setting up a page without main controller

Tags: cakephp

I am a little bit in a pickle with this. I have a page which doesn't have Main Controller or model.. but it will interact with multiple models/controllers in order to get data from different tables.

How should I go about this ? If anyone can help, I greatly appreciate any piece of advice. Thanks a heaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'page' can be a method in an existing controller.

You will need a view for it.

You can create a route for it (so you can call it using /mypage instead of `/my-existing-controller/mypage`.

Comment: Hi @cornelb, it is what I have done so far.. But I got worried that it might not be that 'wise' to put an action which doesn't really 'belong' to a controller. So it's not a very bad practice ? Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: what is the function supposed to do?

Comment: Well, all it does is redirect to the respective view, from where certain functions will be called via ajax (functions which belong to other controllers, including the controller where  the function currently sits. )

Comment: maybe you can put it to appController then? If it does not need a view

Comment: I did not think of that one. I could very easily put it in the appController yes! And it actually makes a little bit more sense I think! Thanks very much